# Vertices of Polyhedral

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, polyhedra

Suppose there are matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider a non-empty polyhedron $P = \{Ax \leq b\} $. Then, there exists a vector $\bar{x}\in P $ such that $A^\prime \bar{x} = b^\prime$ for some nonsingular $p \times p$ submatrix $A^\prime$ of $A$ and a subvector $b^\prime$ of $b$.

This comes from the polyhedral theory, but I have no idea where I start proving the above statement.

Here is my thoughts: since $P$ is not empty, there is a vector $\bar{x}\in P$. This means there is a subsystem $A^\prime x=B^\prime$ with nonsingular square matrix $A$ and the solution of this system is $\bar{x}$. Any comment please?

Comment: Is the inequality intended in the sense of $-b_i \leq (Ax)_i \leq b_i$ for all $n$ components of $b$ and $Ax$? It's not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: @Semiclassical The inequalities are $(Ax)_i\leq b_i$ for all i=1,\ldots,n$. Please let me know if there is anything that I can clarify.

Comment: The reason that seems strange to me is that that region isn't finite in volume, which seems strange for a polyhedron.

Comment: @Semiclassical What I mean by polyhedron here is a set of vectors of the form $P=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Ax\leq b\}$ for some matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and some vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So the definition of polyhedron in this context doesn't require the region to be finite in volume. Fair enough.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, that's right.

Comment: Should the p be m?

Comment: @vdesai $p$ could be $m$ but here $p\leq \max\{n,m\}$.

Comment: My instinct at this point would be to consider a case which can be visualized, like $n=2$ or $r$ with relatively smal $m$, and see if you can find a geometric interpretation of what you're seeing. I _think_ it'll be related to how membership in $P$ can change if you project to a subspace and/or drop some of the inequalities.